# Node JavaScript disable Transfer-Encoding Chunked

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, transfer-encoding

I have an app which sends HTTP responses as chunked.
The chunking itself is done before the HTTP response and is sent as payload to the HTTP server response functions.
When node sees that I have the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` it will take the payload and think that it needs to be chunked. This additional chunking messes things.
Is there any way to make node ignore this header and not to do the additional chunking?

Comment: Are you using Express? In that case you could just set the header manually: `res.header('Transfer-Encoding', '');`

Comment: No node js with the http server. The idea is that the response is chunked so I do need to set the header. A previous part of the application is doing the chunking and I don't need node to do anything with it the behaviour is that it gets the payload already chunked and it chunks it again.